# sql query - just one query for fetch in database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

bellow I have the following structure in the image.

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rImB.jpg)

The purpose of the query is to return which phrases does not exist in the table expression. To get the solution initially I had to use two query.

This first query is returned a counter that related phrases with a few words in the table expression. In the grouping of having clause is placed a limit. For example is fifteen.

```sql
SELECT ex.phrase_id, count(ex.phrase_id) as total FROM Expressions ex
GROUP BY ex.phrase_id
HAVING COUNT(ex.phrase_id) < 15
ORDER BY total desc;
```

In the second query is performed a sub query considering all the words not in the table words. It can be seen that this query uses fixed values for phrase_id 6 and 5 to clause limit. Of course these values are for each variable.

```sql
SELECT all_data.id as 'word_id', all_data.name as 'word_name', all_data.`phrase_id`  FROM
(
SELECT 
    wo.*, 
    '6' AS phrase_id
FROM Words wo
WHERE wo.id NOT IN(
    SELECT ex.word_id FROM Expressions ex WHERE ex.phrase_id = 6
) LIMIT 5 ) AS all_data;
```

Below is the implementation code using the java language.

```java
public void findExpressions() {

    StringBuilder query_phrases_words_not_group = new StringBuilder( 50 );

    query_phrases_words_not_group.append( "SELECT ex.phrase_id, count(ex.phrase_id) as total FROM Expressions ex " );
    query_phrases_words_not_group.append( "GROUP BY ex.phrase_id " );
    query_phrases_words_not_group.append( "HAVING COUNT(ex.phrase_id) < 15 " );
    query_phrases_words_not_group.append( "ORDER BY total desc; " );

    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList( query_phrases_words_not_group.toString() );

    for( Map row : rows ){

        Long phrase_id = ((BigInteger) row.get( "phrase_id" )).longValue();

        Long total = (Long.valueOf(3000) - (Long) row.get( "total" ));

        StringBuilder query_data_group = new StringBuilder(50);
        query_data_group.append( "SELECT all_data.id as 'word_id', all_data.name as 'word_name', all_data.`phrase_id`  FROM " );
        query_data_group.append( "( " );
        query_data_group.append( "SELECT " );
        query_data_group.append( "  wo.*, " );
        query_data_group.append( phrase_id ).append( " AS phrase_id " );
        query_data_group.append( "  FROM Words wo " );
        query_data_group.append( "WHERE wo.id NOT IN( " );
        query_data_group.append( "  SELECT ex.word_id FROM Expressions ex WHERE ex.phrase_id = " ).append( phrase_id );
        query_data_group.append( ") LIMIT 5 ) AS all_data");

        List<Map<String, Object>> data_rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList( query_data_group.toString() );

        for( Map data_row : data_rows ){

            Long word_id = ((BigInteger) data_row.get( "word_id" )).longValue(); 

            String word = (String) data_row.get( "word_id" );

            phrase_id = ((BigInteger) data_row.get( "phrase_id" )).longValue();

        }

    }

}
```

I would like to share with everyone here a better way to make only one query to the database. I imagine that the expected end result would be something like the image.

Comment: So you've done it, it works, and you're just showing us how it works?

Comment: maybe you can try something like select * from words, pharses where concat(words.id,',', pharses.id) not in (select concat(word_id, ',', pharse_id) from expressions)

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo yes, it works fine. But I asked to share if theres is another way to write a new query for only one hint for the database.